# Getting a notification when a local file is accessed in windows

Tags: windows, winapi, synchronization, filesystems

I'd like to get notified when a specific file get accessed (AFAIK, most generally for a `Userland` code - by `CreateFile()` / `NtCreateFile()`)

I already know about `FileSystemWatcher` which should do the same within the `.NET` environment, But I'm working in plain `C` + `WinAPI`.

As for the type of notification , raising a specified `Event` would be perfect, but sending a `callback` to be called , will also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in WinAPI and related links.

Alternatively, when functionality of that function is not enough, you can use a filesystem filter driver (write yours or use our CallbackFilter product).

Comment: `FindFirstChangeNotification()` seems to be what I was looking for. I wonder if `.NET` implements theirs `FileSystemWatcher` with it. BTW, I can't upvote due to lack of reputation, so have my virtual +1 .

Comment: @friedrichkuhler Yes, FileSystemWatcher is just a wrapper.