# File System Watcher of Powershell on Opening a Folder

Tags: windows, powershell, filesystemwatcher

Recently I am trying to build a file system watcher on my computer with Windows 7. I am using FileSystemWatcher of Powershell, it works quite good! I can monitor file/folder creating, deleting, renaming and file changing, including all files and folders in subfolders. But when I want to monitor the situation that user opens a folder, for example by double clicking, I cannot find any event listeners in Powershell for that, but it is quite important for my file system watcher.

Does Powershell have this kind of event listener for getting the event of opening a folder? Or there is another better way to do it.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779616/filesystemwatcher-used-to-watch-for-folder-file-open

Comment: And this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739927/monitor-file-open-c-sharp-net/24753608#24753608

Comment: There is no "event" of opening a folder.. only way is http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399